# Resize intro images in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla3.0

i want to resize intro images as for thumbnail size while uploading in joomla 3

can anyone suggest me any idea or suitable plugin.? I have used smartresizer but it not works.

Answer (score 3):

May be this answer is late but surely someone else might benefit from it, i have used [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/25482) plugin and it works out of the box, it has parameters to set the sizes for introimage or full image

Answer (score 0):

In my joomla websites I always use a dropzone module that upload and resize images on the fly... useful to create intro and full article images in one shot (and works with multiple photos).

Here the link http://mapkcode.com/mk-extensions/mk-dropzone